# Using fabric to copy file from one remote server to another remote server?

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I need to make a service that can copy a file from one remote server to another remote server.  I could just run this in a subshell:

```
scp user@host1:/path/to/file/video.mp4 user@host2:/path/to/file
```

But that doesn't seem nearly as good as using something like fabric's put command, which only copies a local file to a remote machine.  I also need this to run entirely with ssh keys, no password prompting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`get`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.get) to get the file from host1 and then [`put`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put) to push it to host2.

For keys, if the private key isn't in the default location, you can [specify it](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/fab.html#cmdoption-i) with the `-i` flag, e.g.:

```
fab -i /path/to/priv/key
```

or put it in the fabfile:

```
from fabric import env
env.key_filename = '/path/to/priv/key'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was hoping there was a more direct way to do the copy, but this is a good answer.

Comment: I think your solution is more or less the most direct. You could do this on host1: `run('scp file host2:/path/to/file')` as long as you had the ssh keys set up correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Also there is a possibility where [agent forwarding](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/env.html?highlight=forwarding#forward-agent) can be used(as of fabric 1.10, with option -A). In which case you can just run the following command from host1

```
scp /path/to/file/video.mp4 user@host2:/path/to/file
```

or from host2:

```
scp user@host1:/path/to/file/video.mp4 /path/to/file
```